# Why isn't Sublime Text link created?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I'm trying to get Sublime Text 2 to open from Terminal.  I'm using the following:

```
MacBook-Pro:project2 myusername$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/myusername/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.  I'm following all the examples out there.  Am I missing something?

Here's the output of an echo $PATH (updated path):

```
/Users/myusername/bin:/Users/myusername/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

This is on OSX 10.11.1

Answer (score 1):

You most probably do not have a `bin` folder in your home directory. Create one by using

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

This will create the `bin` folder in your `/Users/yourusername/` directory. In terminal the `~` is short for your home.

You will also have to append this folder to your path, i.e. create (or edit if it exists) a `.profile` file in your home directory and give it this content:

```
export PATH=/Users/yourusername/bin:$PATH
```

You will have to open a new terminal for this change to take place.

Comment: Which folder should I be in when I create this?  I've also appended the OP.  It looks like I do have a bin folder: /usr/local/bin.

Comment: /usr/local/bin folder is not the same thing as your /User/username/bin folder. I would suggest that you learn some command line basics. This document might be a bit long but it reading it at least up to the shell input and output would help you greatly https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-TP40003516-SW1

Comment: I also add a bin in myusername.  I ran the command and saw subl was added.  When I run "subl", I get "command not found", even if I'm in the bin folder.

Comment: Did you add the ~/bin path to your .profile? Also, to run a program in the current folder you should use the ./subl syntax. Please do read some command line basics, the SO comment system is not here to expand on the asked questions. If an answer has solved the question in the title then accept it and ask another question if needed.

Comment: If I run ./subl, I get this: "No such file or directory". I've posted what the current PATH looks like.  I have bin folders everywhere now.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these 2 commands:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl
```

or

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  Here's the output: sudo: cannot get working directory
Password: ****
ln: /Users/myusername/bin/subl: No such file or directory